# Matrix multiplication in OpenCV for Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, matrix

I'm new to OpenCV and android. I'm trying to convert an OpenCV C++ code into java. But I'm  stuck in these points. I don't know how to do these operations to Mat Objects. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

**first part-**

```
Mat im1;
im1 = cmyk[3].mul(1 - cmyk[1]) > 0.25;
```

(`cmyk` is a `List<Mat>` object in my java code)

**second part-**

```
im3 = ((255 - im3) & im2) > 200;
```

(im3,im2,im1 all are Mat objects)

Answer (score 0):

The Matrix operations (add, mult, etc.) in OpenCV are in the [core.Core](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html) class.

To multiply two matrices together

```
Core.multiply(mat1,mat2,resultMat)
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. But here I'm doing the operation with some values (eg. 0.25). I checked above method. its takes 2 Mat objects. So I cannot use this.

Comment: @ssdehero There are many functions in the Core class. Amongst them are the [compare](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#compare(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int)) and [bitwise_and](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#bitwise_and(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) that you use in your examples. Please take a closer look at the docs.